# Expand Collapse a row in table

Tags: jquery

I have 3 rows in my table of which I need to have expand collapse functionality on 2 rows i.e. 1st and 3rd row.

I was able to comeup with something on JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/01u0k7o3/). Issue I find is if try collapsing the 1st row, it collapses the second row as well. Is there any way that if I collapse the first row, it just collapses the first row and not anything underneath it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this has to do with SharePoint?

Comment: It is inside a SharePoint WebPart :)

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/01u0k7o3/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at following:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.RowToClick').click(function ()
    {
        $(this).nextAll('tr').each( function()
        {
            if ($(this).is('.row'))
            {
               return false;
            }
            $(this).toggle(350);
       });
    });
 });
```

Simply added a generic class to all the rows and used that to check for toggling.

Comment: Please add more details to this answer, without the jsfiddle it is of no help

Comment: Added the script here